# How to add custom attributes to AttributesToJSON?

Tags: apache-nifi

I have a scenario where list of files are coming from previous processor, where for each file, I have to create json file with attributes of the flowfile. In AttributesToJSON processor configuration there is option to extract pipeline attributes and can create json files/object, if we set Include Core Attributes to true, it will read some of the file properties and forms the json file.
[image]

```
the out for the above case in my scenario is …
{"fragment.size":"125"
file.group:"root",
file.lastModifiedTime:"2020-12-22T15:09:13+0000",
fragment.identifier:"ee5770ea-8406-400a-a2fd-2362bd706fe0",
fragment.index:"1",
file.creationTime:"2020-12-22T15:09:13+0000",
file.lastAccessTime:"2020-12-22T17:34:22+0000",
segment.original.filename:"Sample-Spreadsheet-10000-rows.csv",
file.owner:"root",
fragment.count:"2",
file.permissions:"rw-r--r--",
text.line.count:"1"}
}



 But the files has other properties, like absolute.path, filename, uuid  are missing in the above json file.
    My requirement is, get the absolute.path, filename and uuid and concatenate absolute.path+/+filename, assign this to custom attribute say filepath:absolute.path+/+filename and also add uuid to json object.
```

so my json file should like

{
uuid:"file uuid value",
filepath:"absolute.path+/+filename"
}
any inputs to get above json file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `UpdateAttribute` processor to delete the unnecessary attributes before passing to `AttributestoJSON` or you can also specify the exact attributes you need in the `attributesToJSON` processor.